# How to update an empty node using Xpath navigator

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xpathnavigator

i have an XML like this

```
<main>
  <reportPath>d:\reports</reportPath>
  <errorPath>D:\Error</errorPath>
  <project>D:\xyz.txt</project>
  <value />
</main>
```

here "value" is an empty node. using Xpath navigator, I am able to reach Value node, but not able update it.
using something like :

```
XPathNavigator currentnavigator = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//*/value");
```

Can anyone give me some idea how to edit this node i.e. add value to it which can be a string path.

will  get appended at the end ?

Comment: sorry read <project>D:\xyz.txt<\project>

Comment: you can edit your question by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If your `navigator` is editable, you can just use [`SetValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.setvalue.aspx):

```
currentnavigator.SetValue("somePath");
```

That being said, I would recommend you to use LINQ to XML instead, I find it much easier to use:

```
XDocument doc = …;
doc.Root.Element("value").Value = "somePath";
```